# yaml fileSpec: |

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I am kind of struggling with yaml format of fileSpec: | condition

```
    fileSpec: |
  {
    "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/publish/*.zip",
      "target": "myartifactory/$(Build.DefinitionName)/"
    }
   ]
  }
```

I am getting error: can not read a block mapping entry; a multiline key may not be an implicit key at line 69, column 4:
}
^

Do you know why?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Right now, you're showing an error message that includes a line number higher than the number of lines in the code you show.

Comment: Can you share more configuration of your yaml file? You can refer to this document about [YAML schema reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema).

Comment: YAML is whitespace sensitive. You need to indent the lines after `fileSpec: |` more.